# Многофайловый проект

Tags: c++

Вот такое чудо получилось, не стал все функции вставлять, выводит одни и те же ошибки у каждого направления, впервые столкнулся с многофайловыми проектами, искал в поисковике, вроде бы в основном схоже, не понимаю в чем ошибка. Прошу помощи. Снизу скрин ошибок.

main функция

```
#include "Mnogochlen.h"
#include "Chetyrehchlen.h"
#include "Dvuchlen.h"
#include "Trehchlen.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
int main()
{
    Mnogochlen<T> Mname(4, 5, 6); 
    Mname.foo();
}
```

// Mnogochlen.h

```
#pragma once

template<typename T>
    class Mnogochlen 
    {
    protected:

        T a = 1;
        T b = 1;
        T c = 1;
        double S = a * x * x + b * x + c;
    public:
        Mnogochlen();
        Mnogochlen(T a , T b, T c);
        ~Mnogochlen(); 
        void Set(T a, T b, T c);
        T GetA();
        T GetB();
        T GetC();
        void Show();
        void foo();
    };
```

// Mnogochlen.cpp

```
#include "Mnogochlen.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
Mnogochlen<T>::Mnogochlen(T a, T b, T c)
{
    this->a = a;
    this->b = b;
    this->c = c;
}

template<typename T>
void Mnogochlen<T>::Set(T a, T b, T c)
{
    this->a = a;
    this->b = b;
    this->c = c;
}

template<typename T>
void Mnogochlen<T>::Show()
{
    cout << "a * x * x + b * x + c = 0" << endl;
}
```

// Trehchlen.h

```
#pragma once

template<typename T>
class Trehchlen : public Mnogochlen<T> {
public:
    T S;
    void Set3(T a, T b, T c) : Set(a, b, c);
    void foo3(); // квадрат трехчлена


};

template<typename T>
double operator+(const Trehchlen<T>& a, const Trehchlen<T>& b) {
    return a.S + b.S;
};

template<typename T>
double operator*(const Trehchlen<T>& a, const Trehchlen<T>& b) {
    return a.S * b.S;
};

template<typename T>
double operator/(const Trehchlen<T>& a, const Trehchlen<T>& b) {
    return a.S / b.S;
};
```

Trehchlen.cpp

```
#include "Trehchlen.h"
#include "Mnogochlen.h"

template<typename T>
void Trehchlen<T>::Set3(T a, T b, T c)
{
}

template <typename T>
void Trehchlen<T>::foo3() {
    S = a * a + b * b + c * c + 2 * a * b + 2 * b * c + 2 * a * c;
}
```

[image: Ошибки]

Comment: `template<typename T> int main()` - серьезно? так нельзя.

Comment: `void Set3(T a, T b, T c) : Set(a, b, c);` - ошибка. При декларции функции уберите всё с двоеточеем и дальше.

Comment: @KoVadim просто если так сделать, то выдает отсутствует список аргументов для шаблон классов

Comment: @fofler то есть, остальные ошибки Вас не смущают? Не нужно делать main шаблонным. А функцию вызывайте где то так `nogochlen<int> Mname(4, 5, 6);`

Comment: В определении класса нужно писать только список переменных, а не вызывать функции с неизвестной переменной x. `T a = 1;
        T b = 1;
        T c = 1;
        double S = a * x * x + b * x + c;`

Comment: К показанным вами ошибкам это ни при чем, но потом на линковке выползет, что вы реализацию шаблона запихнули в .cpp-файл. Все, что касается шаблонов - держите в заголовочных файлах..

Comment: Вот смотрите:

    `#include "Trehchlen.h"
    #include "Mnogochlen.h"`

потом у вас идет какой-то текст, ну, неважно. Что видит компилятор в `"Trehchlen.h"`? Он сразу же видит

    `template<typename T>
    class Trehchlen : public Mnogochlen<T> {
    public:`

Но что такое `Mnogochlen`? Ему неизвестно. Вот он и выбрасывает массу ошибок. Как минимум попробуйте поменять местами заголовочные файлы. У вас и других ошибок до фига, но эту пока никто не упомянул...

Answer (score 1):

шаблоны в файле cpp не будут работать как вы ожидаете, так как компилятор компилирует файлы отдельно он не может следить за определениями и обьявлениями, используемыми для инстанцирования шаблона, поэтому на этапе линковки будут ошибки, для решения проблемы можно:

- cpp включать c помощью #include в файл h, но это не рекомендуется
- помещать и обьявление и определение в h файл
- делать явную специализацию шаблона `template class Mnogochlen<int>;`
- вместо cpp написать inl и подключить этот файл в конце h файла